# Create API for geojson data in django

Tags: django, rest, api, gis

I know we can use django rest framework for creating API for normal data. But I'm confused can we use django rest framework  for geojson data. I'm mean i want to build location based web app using django and I also want to manipulate the data from android app or ios app. So here I'm confused can i use django rest framework or somethings else.  Here I'm using PostgreSQL and postgis for data storage.

Comment: I want to perform operations like crud from android app.

Comment: Yes you can. You can have different approaches depending on your needs. You can manage yourself the features using PostGIS queries, you can use GeoDjango, or you can even use a map server and implement a proxy approach with Django. Again it depends on your needs.